# how to use date pipe in an object in angular and format it to JSON for node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Im trying to have the current date as an object property and convert it to Json for node back end. I also don't know if the date property in node will capture the instance from the front end

In angular 2/4 i have

```
const newCustomer = {
   firstName: this.firstName;
   lastName: this.lastName;
   date: number = Date.now();
}
```

My router.post in node

```
router.post('/customers', (req,res,next) =>{

let newCustomer = new Customer({

    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    date: Date.now()


});

newCustomer.save(function(err, Customer){

    if (err){

        res.json({msg: 'Failed to add contact'});

    }else{

        res.json({msg: 'Customer added to waitlist'});

    }
});
```

My model/Schema for customer

```
const customerSchema = new Schema({

date: new Date();

firstName: {
    type: String,
    //required means there has to be a name
    required: true
},

lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the date object as a JSON to the back-end this should be serialized to do so, but you can create a new Date object in your node app parsing the serialized date object. Ref [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)

```
var backendDate = new Date(jsonSerializedDate);
```